# I broke aptitude

Tags: debian, package-management

I tried ro remove some unused packages in debian with aptitude.
Apparently I left some conflicting packages and now aptitude refuses to run (same as apt-get)
I get this error

```
apt-get: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7num_getIcSt19istreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE2idE, version GLIBCXX_3.4
```

The obvious thing for me would be to install aptitude again. But this is an egg and chicken problem...

What should I do? dpkg works.

Comment: What command did you run to remove "unused packages"?

Comment: I fooled around with aptitude itself. I think I created the havoc trying to remove X11 and gcc (I don't use those, it's a webserver).

Comment: LOL, had to give you a point for the title "I broke aptitude"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to install it using the [.deb file](http://packages.debian.org/stable/aptitude) from packages.debian.org.
(scroll to the bottom of the page and select the appropriate architecture)

Comment: lucky me wget still works :-)
I had to download several packages but now everything looks ok.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue, I would immediately UNDO what you've just done; take a look at `/var/log/dpkg.log` for a history of what you removed, and reinstall those packages using `dpkg` and their respective .deb files from http://packages.debian.org.

If you still want to find out what package (specifically) caused this failure, use the same list of packages above, and uninstall them one at a time until you run into the error.